# Metodos de intent para enviar email

Tags: android

Alguem poderia me esclarecer o seguinte codigo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject of email");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body of email");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:default@recipient.com"));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Em `setType("text/plain");` qual o parâmetro e o que seria o método em si?

Como é o funcionamento do `puExtra();` e do `setData();`, não são métodos semelhantes?

O que seria o `addFlags();`? Quais parâmetros ele pode receber?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, vamos lá:

**1 -** **setType()**:
Define um tipo de dados MIME explícito.
 - Isto é usado para criar intents que só especificam um tipo e não dados, por exemplo, para indicar o tipo de dados que deve retornar.
 - Este método limpa automaticamente todos os dados que foram previamente definidos (por exemplo, por setData (Uri)).

Nota: O tipo de correspondência MIME no âmbito Android é sensível a maiúsculas, ao contrário de tipos formais RFC MIME. Como resultado, você deve sempre escrever seus tipos MIME com letras minúsculas, ou usar normalizeMimeType (String) ou setTypeAndNormalize (String) para garantir que ele é convertido para minúsculas.

parâmetros:
type: String: O tipo MIME dos dados a ser tratados por este intent.
retorno:
Retorna o mesmo objeto intent, para encadear várias chamadas em uma única instrução.

**2 -** putExtra e setData:
Não, não são métodos semelhantes, veja:
**putExtra()**:

- Adiciona dados estendidos ao intent. O nome deve incluir um prefixo do pacote, por exemplo, o aplicativo com.android.contacts, usaria nomes como "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

**setData()**:

- Define os dados com que este intent irá operar daqui por diante. Este método limpa automaticamente qualquer tipo que foi previamente definido pelo setType (String) ou setTypeAndNormalize (String).

**3 -** **setFlags():**
Define sinalizadores especiais que controlam como este intent será tratado. A maioria dos valores aqui dependem do tipo de componente que está sendo executado pelo Intent, especificamente as bandeiras FLAG_ACTIVITY_* são todas para uso com Context.startActivity () e as bandeiras FLAG_RECEIVER_*  são todas para uso com Context.sendBroadcast ().

Veja [Tasks and Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) para obter informações importantes sobre a forma como algumas dessas opções afetam o comportamento do seu aplicativo.

no mais é isso e pelo que pude ver parece que você tá começando agora com programação para android, entaum, seguem algumas dicas:

1 - aprenda ingles;
2 - Estude cara, essa resposta eu traduzi do google developer console que foi facilmente encontrado quando eu solicitei "intent.addflags" no campo de busca.

luz e paz!